# Rails5 add references to create one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I create two models call `Restaurant` and `menu`, and Restaurant has_many Menu.
I create Menu by typing

```
rails g model Menu name restaurant:references
```

But I found out I can't create Menu by type `Menu.create(name: "test1")`

```
m1 = Menu.create(name: "test1")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<Menu id: nil, name: "test1", restaurant_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Then I checked the `migration` and `schema`, in Rails5 migration the `references`  become this

```
#Menu migration
...
t.references :restaurant, foreign_key: true
```

I thought in Rails4, it would be somthing like

```
t.references :restaurant, index: true
```

Is that the reason I could not create meun?

### Update

Here is migration file

```
class CreateMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :menus do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :restaurant, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run the migration?

Comment: Can you post your migration file?

Comment: I did run the migration and I've update the migration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create the menu because your migration includes a foreign key constraint on `restaurant_id`, meaning a menu can't be created without a restaurant (similarly a restaurant can't be destroyed if associated menus exist). If this is your intent, you'll need to either provide a valid `restaurant_id` when creating the menu or create it through the association on `restaurant`

```
@restaurant.menus.create(name: 'test1')
```

If you don't need the foreign key constraint, modify the migration and remove the `:foreign_key` option. If doing this, set the `:index` option to true.